# SOAP Webservice is giving the below error- Invocation target exception

Tags: soap, java-8, jar, axis

thrown exception, unwinding now

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Error invoking remote service: ; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
Caused by: com.sample.base.adapter.ef.subscriptionhandler2.SubscriptionHandler2Exception: Error invoking remote service: ; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments
```

Comment: I used axis 1.4 and jdk 8 please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Kindly show your code.  You are trying to cast an AttachmentsImpl to Attachments.  does `AttachmentsImpl implement Attachments`?  If yes, and you think it is odd that it is not working.  It probably means there are 2 different versions of Axis in your libraries/dependencies.   You probably have a version, where `AttachmentsImpl` does not implement `Attachment`

Comment: There are two services for example service1 and service 2 , if I restart the server service1 works well, service2 gives the above error, again if I restart the server service 2 works well service 1 gives the above error, I can see both services are using the same adapter code and packaged separately, and I can see both services using Axis 1.4 jar

Comment: I am not sure what is causing for this error , Please help me on this!